# Optimization over a function space with one discrete variable and one continuous variable

Tags: python, algorithm, optimization, scipy, mathematical-optimization

According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_optimization), a minimization problem can be described in the following way:

> Given: a function *f* : *A* → *ℝ* from some set *A* to real numbers
>
> Sought: an element *x<sub>0</sub>* ∈ *A* such that *f*(*x<sub>0</sub>*) ≤ *f*(*x*) for all *x* ∈ *A*.

However, I am now facing a different minimization problem, where the objective function returns a function instead of a real number. The function has two variables, one is the input variable `x`, the other is an unknown variable `z` within a known interval. The problem can be described as

> Given: a function *f*: *A* → ℱ(*x*, *z*) from some set *A* to a function space ℱ(*x*, *z*) where *z* ∈ [*a*, *b*]
>
> Sought: a maximum subset *B* ⊆ *A*, where for each element *x<sub>0</sub>* ∈ *B*, there exists at least one interval of z ∈ [*c*, *d*] (*a* ≤ *c* < *d* ≤ *b*), such that *f*(*x<sub>0</sub>*, *z*) ≤ *f*(*x*, *z*) for all *x* ∈ *A*.

Say I have a set of 200 **discrete** integers `x` from 0 to 200, and a **continuous** `z` ranging from 0 to 100. Each `x` corresponds to a unique function `f(x, z)`, which is the objective that I want to minimize. If we plot all `f(x, z)` functions with different `x` together, my goal is to get the lowest curve, consisting of all parts of `f(x, z)` functions with their corresponding `z` intervals.

It baffles me how to even approach this kind of optimization problem. For a small set of 200 data, a brute force minimization is feasible. However, since `z` is continuous, I don't know any solution other than discretizing `z`, and optimize `x` for each discretized `z`. I managed to write the following Python code, which gives me a dictionary containing the information of the lowest curve. In the dictionary, each key is a `z` interval, and each value is the function `f(x, z)` on that interval with a unique `x`.

```
from scipy.optimize import fsolve
import numpy as np

def f(x, z, noise):
    return x**2 - 2*x*(z+noise) + (z+noise)**2

xs = np.arange(200)
np.random.seed(77)
# Add noise to each f(x,z) depending on x to make them look different
noises = np.random.normal(0, 2, 200)
fmins = []
# Discretize z
zs = np.linspace(0, 100)
# Append f(x,z) functions to the list in increasing order of z
for zi in zs:
    y = f(xs, zi, noises)
    imin = np.argmin(y)
    fmin = lambda z, x=xs[imin], noise=noises[imin]: f(x, z, noise)
    fmins.append(fmin)

# Calculate z intersections between consecutive functions
intersects = [fsolve(lambda x: f2(x) - f1(x), np.array([50]))[0]
              for f1, f2 in zip(fmins[:-1], fmins[1:])]
intersects = [min(zs)] + intersects + [max(zs)]
d = {}
for i, fmin in enumerate(fmins):
    interval = (intersects[i], intersects[i+1])
    d[interval] = fmin

print(d)
```

Output:

```
{(0.0, 0.9306572035798859): <function <lambda> at 0x7f3e1194a940>, 
 (0.9306572035798859, 3.523791768941706): <function <lambda> at 0x7f3de48b6310>, 
 (3.523791768941706, 5.156055079788118): <function <lambda> at 0x7f3de48b63a0>, 
 (5.156055079788118, 7.060509829231237): <function <lambda> at 0x7f3de48b6430>, 
 (7.060509829231237, 9.411863014512925): <function <lambda> at 0x7f3de48b64c0>, 
 (9.411863014512925, 10.878375941003492): <function <lambda> at 0x7f3de48b6550>, 
 (10.878375941003492, 12.851666158200706): <function <lambda> at 0x7f3de48b65e0>, 
 (12.851666158200706, 14.688146181666877): <function <lambda> at 0x7f3de48b6670>, 
 (14.688146181666877, 16.925166092978166): <function <lambda> at 0x7f3de48b6700>, 
 (16.925166092978166, 19.394908778511684): <function <lambda> at 0x7f3de48b6790>, 
 (19.394908778511684, 21.305777491683568): <function <lambda> at 0x7f3de48b6820>, 
 (21.305777491683568, 23.2027948221009): <function <lambda> at 0x7f3de48b68b0>, 
 (23.2027948221009, 25.780004035272682): <function <lambda> at 0x7f3de48b6940>, 
 (25.780004035272682, 27.982290799636893): <function <lambda> at 0x7f3de48b69d0>, 
 (27.982290799636893, 29.808147413619455): <function <lambda> at 0x7f3de48b6a60>, 
 (29.808147413619455, 31.981063365806524): <function <lambda> at 0x7f3de48b6af0>, 
 (31.981063365806524, 33.4500512896996): <function <lambda> at 0x7f3de48b6b80>, 
 (33.4500512896996, 35.29397765315358): <function <lambda> at 0x7f3de48b6c10>, 
 (35.29397765315358, 38.10407179754019): <function <lambda> at 0x7f3de48b6ca0>, 
 (38.10407179754019, 40.47737143083045): <function <lambda> at 0x7f3de48b6d30>, 
 (40.47737143083045, 42.13030387266737): <function <lambda> at 0x7f3de48b6dc0>, 
 (42.13030387266737, 44.159176436708734): <function <lambda> at 0x7f3de48b6e50>, 
 (44.159176436708734, 46.05615327288865): <function <lambda> at 0x7f3de48b6ee0>, 
 (46.05615327288865, 48.04028067812315): <function <lambda> at 0x7f3de48b6f70>, 
 (48.04028067812315, 50.231509599269444): <function <lambda> at 0x7f3de48b8040>, 
 (50.231509599269444, 52.19280606828053): <function <lambda> at 0x7f3de48b80d0>, 
 (52.19280606828053, 53.71414629493223): <function <lambda> at 0x7f3de48b8160>, 
 (53.71414629493223, 55.779247993613474): <function <lambda> at 0x7f3de48b81f0>, 
 (55.779247993613474, 57.72958863695487): <function <lambda> at 0x7f3de48b8280>, 
 (57.72958863695487, 59.49891225446917): <function <lambda> at 0x7f3de48b8310>, 
 (59.49891225446917, 61.951752539105094): <function <lambda> at 0x7f3de48b83a0>, 
 (61.951752539105094, 64.05090162687272): <function <lambda> at 0x7f3de48b8430>, 
 (64.05090162687272, 66.27833580896989): <function <lambda> at 0x7f3de48b84c0>, 
 (66.27833580896989, 68.37813383380094): <function <lambda> at 0x7f3de48b8550>, 
 (68.37813383380094, 69.91114393992471): <function <lambda> at 0x7f3de48b85e0>, 
 (69.91114393992471, 72.11458525139145): <function <lambda> at 0x7f3de48b8670>, 
 (72.11458525139145, 74.403469722199): <function <lambda> at 0x7f3de48b8700>, 
 (74.403469722199, 76.43027400630706): <function <lambda> at 0x7f3de48b8790>, 
 (76.43027400630706, 78.88031368050711): <function <lambda> at 0x7f3de48b8820>, 
 (78.88031368050711, 80.98238578016664): <function <lambda> at 0x7f3de48b88b0>, 
 (80.98238578016664, 82.28765648953089): <function <lambda> at 0x7f3de48b8940>, 
 (82.28765648953089, 84.58399253904847): <function <lambda> at 0x7f3de48b89d0>, 
 (84.58399253904847, 86.92718588543782): <function <lambda> at 0x7f3de48b8a60>, 
 (86.92718588543782, 88.62072772046625): <function <lambda> at 0x7f3de48b8af0>, 
 (88.62072772046625, 90.80515807066973): <function <lambda> at 0x7f3de48b8b80>, 
 (90.80515807066973, 92.98553989314603): <function <lambda> at 0x7f3de48b8c10>, 
 (92.98553989314603, 94.31996133855004): <function <lambda> at 0x7f3de48b8ca0>, 
 (94.31996133855004, 96.23167523215874): <function <lambda> at 0x7f3de48b8d30>, 
 (96.23167523215874, 99.10669741301686): <function <lambda> at 0x7f3de48b8dc0>, 
 (99.10669741301686, 100.0): <function <lambda> at 0x7f3de48b8e50>}
```

However, there are two major issues:

1. By discretizing the continuous `z`, I most likely will not get the maximum subset of `x` when there are not enough discretized `z`. Is there anyway to do this without discretization, maybe using integral?
2. When the data set is large, I cannot use brute force to calculate the function for all `x`. Is there any algorithm that can solve this problem relatively fast?

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: I don't completely understand what your goal is, but MINLP solvers exist to solve problems with both discrete and continuous decision variables. (MINLP=Mixed Integer Nonlinear Programming).

Comment: Like Erwin, I have only a vague understanding of what you are trying to achieve. However it seems that you have a way to generate a (continuous) function f from a parameter x. If that is in an algebraic form, then you should be able to do some calculus on it's more general form and e.g. find another function which is the derivative of f wrt z for each x, which will let you find the values of z that are turning points where f would be maximised or minimised. Then you would at least know where to look for the maximum of your function f for each x.